Tkinter bind command to Listbox delay
recently I've made a global function for my program (instead of many locals) that when pressing on a Listbox item -> it will put its text inside the entry widget, kind of "autocomplete" method (like in the image)..
the problem that I'm facing is that now when I made the local "autocomplete" functions into one global one there's delay by one iteration between the Listbox item that you're clicking to the text that it will output to you in the Entry widget.
New fucntion:
   @staticmethod
    def fill_by_click(ui_element, event, listbox):
        ui_element.delete(0, END)
        ui_element.insert(END, listbox.get(ACTIVE))


    def somefunction(self):
       self.functions_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda e: self.fill_by_click(self.find_function, e, self.functions_list))

older ones:
      def somefunction(self):
         def insert_entry(term):
            self.find_text_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.find_text_entry.insert(END, popular_terms.get(ACTIVE))
          popular_terms.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', insert_entry)
 

it's probably a combination of using lambda and giving widget as parameters but I don't know how to resolve it.
I've tried to make some solution, but I've ended only with some dirty and chunky ones.

Try to use listbox.selection_get() instead of listbox.get(ACTIVE)

thanks, it's making that the Combobox text is also triggering the function and outputs also its text, but this still a good solution, thank you

Try Using listbox.get(ANCHOR) instead.


that when pressing on a Listbox item -> it will put its text inside
the entry widget, kind of "autocomplete"

The problem can be fixed.
You must iterate through Listbox by using curselection().
In Listbox, use this to selectmode=tk.EXTENDED
Use an event to trigger the Llistbox.
I noticed a workaround with the fill_by_click() function. So you can suit your needs..
Snippet workaround:
import tkinter as tk


class App():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

        self.langs = ('Java', 'C#', 'C', 'C++', 'Python',
                      'Go', 'JavaScript', 'PHP', 'Swift')

        self.var = tk.Variable(value=self.langs)
      
        lstbox = tk.Listbox(self.parent, selectmode=tk.EXTENDED, listvariable=self.var)
        lstbox.pack()
        ui_elemen = tk.Entry(self.parent)
        ui_elemen.pack()

        @staticmethod
        def fill_by_click(event):
            selected_indices = lstbox.curselection()
            selected_langs = ",".join([lstbox.get(i) for i in selected_indices])
            
            print(selected_langs)
                                      
            ui_elemen.delete(0, tk.END)
            ui_elemen.insert(tk.END, selected_langs)
                 
        
        lstbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', fill_by_click)          

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()

Screenshot:

